# How to transform the matrix/data.frame in R like this?

Tags: r, statistics

For example, `col1`, `col2` are column names, `r1`, `r2` are row names, liek this:

```
   col1 col2
r1    1    4
r2    2    5
```

Is there a function in `Base` or `plyr`to transform it to the following form(3-column data.frame)?

```
r1    col1 1
r1    col2 4
r2    col1 2
r2    col2 5
```

Thanks!

Comment: `stack` from base does this as well.  For more complicated dataframes you may be after `reshape`

Comment: looks like you got on the right path, but packages `reshape` and `reshape2` are quite handy for this, specifically `melt` and `cast`. In base R, there is `stack, unstack, and reshape`. Searching for terms like "long data" and "wide data" will probably be insightful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it.
`melt` function can do it.